# How to reset the view of Eclipse worspace

Tags: java, javascript, android, eclipse

I don't know what I did to my eclipse program but here is a screenshot of what it looks like. Can someone help me reset my eclipse how its suppose to be.

Heres a link of how my workspace looks
http://pic100.picturetrail.com/VOL880/5927631/12798052/410239815.jpg

Comment: Please don't use chat abbreviation (such as IDK)

Comment: I am not sure if you know this already, but in case you don't: when an answer to your question is posted, and it satisfies you, you can click on a check (it is under the score of the answer), to mark it as "Accepted", which will give you 2 reputation points, and help the person who answered it.

Answer (score 1):

In the top right corner, click on ***Java*** (You have ***Java Browsing*** selected)

[image]

After that, you can always *Reset Perspective* (**Window** => **Reset Perspective**)

[image]